# Java runtime errors not showing in Eclipse console for particular project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a J2EE application that I inherited. I have the code setup to run on a JBoss server inside my Eclipse IDE. 
(Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1))

When I start up the server, i can see the server startup info in the console. I can see log4j INFO output. I can see System.out in the console.  Same goes for the JUNIT tests I run inside the IDE.  The one thing that is not showing up in the console are any JAVA runtime errors.  I can look in the jboss log file to see them, but that for the JUNIT tests it is more difficult.

Does anyone know how to get my Java runtime errors to show up in the Eclipse console?

Note: I don't have this problem with other projects using the same Eclipse install. I have also tried recreating my workspace.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your projects log4j configuration?

Comment: `# The logging properties used during tests   
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
    log4j.logger.org.switchyard.component.resteasy=DEBUG   

# Console appender   
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1} - %m%n`

Answer (score 0):

After adding this line:

> -Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false

on the end of "VM arguments" (Server tab -> JBoss Properties -> Open lauch configuration), every runtime error started to show up for me.

Saw that: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717329/eclipse-console-not-showing-any-error-log-output)